# Mentioning travel dates in invite letter for UK visa

Tags: visas, uk, business-travel, invitation-letters

I am applying for UK business visa and my employer sent me this invite letter.

I have two main concerns about this letter:

1. They have written that my trip is tentative.
2. It is mentioned that the company will be bearing my **travel expenses**

Is it alright to mention that my business trip is tentative? Will the granting officers think that I am uncertain about the trip and hence reject the visa?

In the application form I have mentioned that all the expenses will be borne by them (flight, hotel and per-diem). But from the invite letter, it looks like they are providing just the flight expenses.

> We are pleased to invite Mr. X, Designation/employee of ABC Private Ltd. (Group Holding Company) to visit us in London for business
>   meetings and discussions from ab/cd/efgh - ij/kl/mnop [a tentative
>   trip]
>
> His passport details are as follows:
>
> ... Passport details ...
>
> Please note that, all travelling expenses will be borne by the
>   company. We would greatly appreciate if Mr. X can be granted Two
>   month's multiple entries visa.

Comment: Have you asked your employer to clarify what they mean by ‘travelling expenses’ and give you another invitation letter that is more explicit (including removing the reference to a tentative trip)?

Comment: @Traveller The employer is clear on the meaning of 'travelling expenses', for them it means all expenses (flight + acco + food etc.). But this meaning needs to be communicated to the ECO. And they have removed the reference to tentative trip now.